# Stripe Angular Form Doesn't work in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why doesn't this work?  (As in, why doesn't the script actually run and create the payment button as it would if it wasn't in the directive.)

```
.directive('stripeForm', ['$log', function($log) {
  return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    var markup = '<form action="/charge" method="POST">\
      <script\
      src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"\
      data-key="xxx"\
      data-image="/square-image.png"\
      data-name="Demo Site"\
      data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"\
      data-amount="2000">\
      </script>\
    </form>';
    elem.append(angular.element(markup));
  };
}]);
```

The below plunkr demonstrates this issue has nothing at all to do with "data-key" or "data-image" or "data-*".  It simply doesn't work if it is a directive.  The script tag, for whatever reason, does not actually fetch the checkout.js and run the script if it is injected into the DOM in this fashion.

http://plnkr.co/edit/GZC0XlqVM2b1J3ozpHJA?p=preview

My only question is why?

Comment: I don't think this is sufficient information to answer your question. a Jsfiddle might be more valuable in trying to help debug your problem. That way, we can see the html and javascript and how they interact.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/W9B7Rm?p=preview

Comment: It looks like the html is being rendered -- I wonder if it's because data-key is "xxx" or just that it can't find "/square-image.png"

Comment: I updated with a plunkr that shows how it would work if it wasn't in a directive, and how it doesn't work at all if it is in a directive like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gAdG0VBeMxKlLPs0SAFl?p=preview):

```
var form =  document.createElement("form");;
form.action = "charge";
form.method = "POST";
var script =  document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js";
script.className = "stripe-button";
script.setAttribute("data-key", "pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh");
script.setAttribute("data-image", "square-image.png");
script.setAttribute("data-name", "Demo Site");
script.setAttribute("data-description", "2 widgets ($20.00)");
script.setAttribute("data-amount", "2000");

form.appendChild(script);

elem.append(angular.element(form));
```

What I did was creating the elements manually as native objects. Maybe the problem was converting given html markup with angular.element()

Hope it helps